# What is the cartesian equation of $r = 1 + r \sin(\theta)?$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

There are no values given for $r$, or $\theta$. How do I derive the cartesian equation for this? It's a question from a textbook I have.

Comment: Well, r^2 = x^2 + y^2 and tan(theta) = y/x, and go from there.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $ \ r \sin \theta \ $ in that term on the right-hand side, or maybe $ \ a \sin \theta \ $ ?  If it is as shown presently, you can replace $ \ \sin \theta \ $ by $ \ \frac{y}{r} \ $ , then square both sides, and replace $ \ r^2 \ $ with $ \ x^2 + y^2 \ . $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the polar function:
 $$r = 1 + r \sin \theta$$

1. Square everything:
   $$r^2 = 1 + 2 r \sin\theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta$$
2. Substitute $(r^2 = x^2+y^2)$ and $(r \sin\theta = y)$:
   $$x^2 + y^2 = 1 + 2 y + y^2$$
3. Cancel common terms:
   $$x^2 = 1 + 2y$$
4. Rearrange into an expression of y as a function of x:
   $$y = \frac{x^2-1} 2$$