# What is the cartesian equation of $r = 4 + \frac{\sin(\theta)}{2}?$

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

This is extremely similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727138/what-is-the-cartesian-equation-of-r-1-r-sin-theta), but as there is no r next to the constant 1, when I multiply everything by r I'm going to end up with:

$r^2 = 4r +  r\frac{\sin(\theta)}{2}$

And I don't see how to cancel out the 4r with the $x^2+y^2 = r$ identity.

How should I approach this?

And while I'm at it, how should I approach $r = \sin^2\theta?$ Again, multiplying by r would leave me with $r^2 = r\sin^2\theta$ and would still have a theta remaining once I pulled out $r\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $r>0,$

$$2r^2=8r+r\sin\theta\implies2(x^2+y^2)-y=8r=8\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

squaring both sides we get  $$(2(x^2+y^2)-y)^2=64(x^2+y^2)$$

Mind you the original relationship needs $2(x^2+y^2)-y=8r>0$

Comment: So for the other one, am I able to assume that I can multiple by sides by r^2, get $r^3=r^2sin^2\theta$, and interpret that as $(y^2+x^2)(\sqrt(x^2+y^2))=y^2$?

Comment: @Calculisteninghelplessly, Agreed

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much.

Comment: You don't need to assume $r>0$, it is necessarily true, since $r = 4 + \frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)$, and $\sin(\theta) \geq -1$, you have $r \geq \frac{7}{2}$.

Comment: @PerryIverson, Good Observation for the current case But in general we assume $r>0$ right in such cases